# how to create table of contents - specific numeration in open office

Tags: ms-word, openoffice-writer, tableofcontents

How to create table of contents in OpenOffice/Word in this way:

```
Table of contents...... 2

Begin......4

Chapter 1......5

    3.1 Subchapter1...7
```

and so on.

I need to number only subchapter (Header 2 in hierarchy, eq 3.1), but i don't want number main chapter (or the number should be invincibility in the document)

Comment: This is not related to programming anyhow. Please consider asking on the superusers@stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

In [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/):

Got to menu `Tools` -> `Outline Numbering`, and set the numbering only for level 2. not level 1 (first, select the `Level` at the left; then, select the numbering, separator and so on for this level):

[image]